# Add an XsltListViewWebPart to a site defintion homepage

Tags: list-view, site-definition

What's the best method for adding an XsltListViewWebPart to a site definition's default.aspx?

I've tried to add one to the definition's default.aspx declaratively by copying the XML from an existing page, but there are a number of references to view and list guids which I won't have until the site is provisioned. The alternative was to programmatically add to the default.aspx via a site provisioned or feature activated event handler, but it's impossible to get a reference to the default.aspx until the site has been created.

Answer (score 1):

There is a WebProvisioned event receiver you can how hook into in 2010.

This executes once the pages are loaded, have a looksie at this:

http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/webprovisioned-event-receiver-practical.html

Answer (score 0):

Is the list the WebPart needs to look at is also provisioned as part of the Site Definition?

If so, rather than using the `AllUsersWebPart` element in the definition, you can use the [`View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms430995.aspx) element.

Some of the out of the box site definitions do this (Like Blog) so you can look at them for a starting point.